# Vaadin caption invisible in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, components, compatibility, vaadin

I got the problem with display caption of components which are setEnabled to false - the caption for example is not visible or so much white:

[image]

I don't have this problem in Firefox.

Example above:
I created a class which extends FormLayout
and put some components like TextField, CheckBox, then the whole panel is setEnabled(false/true).

How can I make the caption visible in IE?

Comment: Which IE version on what OS version?
Which theme did you use?

Comment: I check compatibility on IE 11 in developer mode for(IE 9-11), OS is a win 7, I use my custom theme, also I add that on IE 10 there is no problem with this view.
It may depends on theme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for IE is set custom CSS style

```
.v-disabled {
opacity: black !important;
efilter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```